# CIFS: VFS: cifs_set lk failed rc=-5

Tags: mount, 22.04, fstab, cifs

I have just upgraded my 20.04 LTS to 22.04 LTS.
No the console every 3-5 second is logging "CIFS: VFS: cifs_set lk failed rc=-5".

I have 2 cifs mount in fstab, so I assume it's those, but the work read/write.
The 2 lines is:

```
//syno.serv.dk/DockerStore /netshares/ds1511/dockerstore cifs noperm,_netdev,credentials=/root/.dockercred 0 0
//syno.serv.dk/DockerConf /netshares/ds1511/dockerconf cifs noperm,_netdev,credentials=/root/.dockercred 0 0
```

Can anyone help with, how to get rid of this error?

Regards Lars Mortensen

Answer (score 0):

Update.
I think it might have been because of the disk being full.
Don't know why, but one of my docker containers started to fill out its swap file which filled up the drive.

No everything is running again.

Regards.